# Granting MySQL permissions to all but one table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database that is used to store data for various applications. I want to grant users permissions to select data from these tables, however there is one table that has sensitive information that only one specific 'special' user should have access to.

How do i grant permissions to all tables EXCEPT that one table. If i grant all, then revoke on that table, it won't work as it says that there is no permission on that table.

I thought about writing a query that could do this, but what happens when tables are added to the database? I would have to go and add that permission to each of the users, which could get quite time consuming. Is there any way to do this easily in MySQL? Perhaps a trigger that on table creation grants permissions? Is that possible?

Comment: NOt good to give "root" access to anything .. since you will never know who used root when it is accessed.  Use a special user instead. If you want strong security and the ability to hide database implementation, you might also consider using stored procedures to access data and set your permissions on who can access the stored procedures with only stored procedures able to access the tables.  Just a thought.

Comment: my bad, it does have a special user for it.

Answer (score 0):

Put that table in a separate database. Then you can grant access to `regulardb.*` to all the normal users, and grant access to `sensitivedb.specialtable` only to the special username.

Comment: This might be a pretty decent solution, but then the problem comes in when databases are added, however to be fair, that won't happen that often. Is there a way to go one step further and avoid that as well?

Comment: I don't think so. There's just one level of grouping, and that's the only way to assign access without having to list each table individually.